# Oracle SQL using Like and wildcard

Tags: oracle, select, wildcard

I am using the following query to find the names of tables in my database:

```
SELECT  table_name
FROM    user_tables
WHERE   table_name LIKE 'APP_X_%'
```

The results that I WANT are:

```
APP_X_ABC
APP_X_DEF
APP_X_GHI
```

The results I am GETTING are:

```
APP_XYZ
APP_X123
APP_X_ABC
APP_X_DEF
APP_X_GHI
```

I need to ONLY return the table names that have the underscore after the X. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`ESCAPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) clause:

> **You can include the actual characters % or _ in the pattern by using the ESCAPE clause, which identifies the escape character. If the escape character precedes the character % or _ in the pattern, then Oracle interprets this character literally in the pattern rather than as a special pattern-matching character.** You can also search for the escape character itself by repeating it.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'APP!_X!_%' ESCAPE '!';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f162ef378e27ba29c99711f7c4382aa2)**

`_` is treated as wildcard (any single character). But you need `_` as literal.